# How safe is an encrypted PDF? (no SSL certificate)

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, itext

Users of our website need to download a PDF that serves as proof that a transaction has been performed.

For security purposes I need to ensure that users cannot edit the PDF (i.e. edit the PDF, change some values, and send it back saying our system made a mistake).

I know *signing* the PDF is a good option, but would prefer to avoid doing this as we would need a dynamic signing certificate device from Adobe which I'm told is quite expensive.

So my question: using iTextSharp's SetEncryption method, is the PDF safe against user modification? Even if the user is a programmer? It appears to be but I would like to make sure.

My encryption code (pasted from another post on StackOverflow :)  ):

```
Console.WriteLine("Creating...");
var file = File.CreateText(fileName);

using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
        document, file.BaseStream);
    writer.SetEncryption(
        null, //No user password
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ownerPassword"),
        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING
            | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY
        ,
        PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128
    );
    document.Open();
    document.Add(new Paragraph("hello world"));
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a "dynamic signing certificate device from Adobe" to sign a PDF? You can sign a PDF with iText and a certificate. Adobe does not need to be in this process.

Comment: +1 regarding Michaël's comment: you can easily create a public/private keypair e.g. using keytool (if you can live with a yellow triangle instead of a green check mark). As for encrypting with an owner password: that protection is only psychological: it can easily be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the comments pointing out that signing and announcing that only documents signed by you are valid is *the way* to go and does not depend on Adobe specific hardware (storing a hash - or a copy - locally won't help, though, you have no prove that what you have stored locally is what you sent the customer), here an answer to your original question:

> using iTextSharp's SetEncryption method, is the PDF safe against user modification? Even if the user is a programmer? It appears to be but I would like to make sure.

No. Anyone who can open the PDF in a PDF Reader (i.e. the PDF is encrypted only by owner password or by owner password and a *known* user password), can circumvent encryption. And after the act that person can also re-encrypt. Probably he will use a different owner password, but how can you prove that the owner password you claim to use actually was used in the PDF sent to the user?

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a bit spurious and long winded, but if you calculate the SHA hash before you send it, and store it in the database, you could provide support with a way to validate that the PDF output is the exact one the server generated. Certainly it is long winded, but could be used as a defence against fraud.

Comment: Why not just sign the document using a home-made public/private key pair? That way, you only have to make sure nobody steals your private key. Validation can be done using Adobe Reader.

Comment: I've removed iTextSharp from your question as there's nothing specific to iTextSharp when looking at encryption. Whoever reads ISO-32000-1 knows how to remove the owner password if there is no user password.